# How to a NHibernate subquery in Where clause with LINQ?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to write a correlated subquery in the where clause like this:

```
var foo = from d in session.Query<Document>()
          where true == 
              ( from a in session.Query<ACLEntry>()
                where a.Id == d.Id || a.Id == null
                select a.Result
              ).FirstOrDefault()
          select d;
```

The expected SQL output is very similar to [this unanswered question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220744/nhibernate-3-2-linq-with-correlated-subquery).

I think the Linq statement itself is fine because I can get it to run in LinqPad where I was prototyping. But NHibernate throws me these mysterious errors:

> ERROR NHibernate.Hql.Parser [(null)] - NoViableAltException(86@[])
>
> ERROR NHibernate.Hql.Parser [(null)] - MismatchedTreeNodeException(72!=3)

Is this an unsupported scenario with the NHibernate LINQ provider? Any ideas on how I might be able to restructure this query to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
var foo = from d in session.Query<Document>()
          where (from a in session.Query<ACLEntry>()
                  where a.Id == d.Id || a.Id == null
                  select a.Result
                 ).FirstOrDefault() != null
          select d;
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: That works (in the sense there are no NH errors), but the query it generates looks like this: `select * from Document where (select TOP 1 blah blah blah) is not null`. However, I need it to end with `= 1` instead. But that's pretty much back to my original query and error.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably having some trouble parsing the `true == ...` portion of the query.

Might want to try this instead,

```
var foo = from d in session.Query<Document>()
    where (from a in session.Query<ACLEntry>()
           where a.Id == d.Id || a.Id == null
           select a.Result
          ).FirstOrDefault()
    select d;
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the thing is that `Result` is a bool in both my class and the database table so I don't understand why I can't query it that way. Having said that, it does indeed work if I change everything (both my class and database column) to an int and run the query like you've shown. What's special about `bool` that causes it to fail? Again, the exact same query works fine if I run it in LinqPad, so I'm inclined to think it's really something breaking in NHibernate's Linq provider.

Comment: In that case you don't need to specify `true == ...`. I updated my answer to express what I mean.